# Effect of closing descriptor for pipe

Tags: pipe, posix, file-descriptor

I have this piece of code which does the same work as 
**ls -l | wc -l**.

```
 main ()
{
  int i;
  int p[2];
  pid_t ret;
  pipe (p);
  ret = fork ();

  if (ret == 0)
    {
      close (1);
      dup (p[1]);
      close (p[0]);
      execlp ("ls", "ls", "-l", (char *) 0);
    }

  if (ret > 0)
    {
      close (0);
      dup (p[0]);
     close (p[1]);
     // wait (NULL);
      execlp ("wc", "wc", "-l", (char *) 0);
    }
}
```

The code works fine but once i comment the line for closing the p[1] in parent , it does not work, rather it gets blocked.
I know that read() does not work if there are no writers and vice versa.
But i cannot figure out what could be the problem in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wc` stops when there isn't any more input. So even if the child finished writing to the pipe, the parent waits for more input from itself because `p[1]` on it's side isn't closed.

So by closing `p[1]`, the parent process expresses it's intent that isn't going to provide input to itself.

I would also suggest using `dup2`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main () {
  int p[2];
  pid_t ret;
  pipe(p);
  ret = fork();

  if (ret == 0) {
    close(p[0]);
    dup2(p[1], 1);
    execlp ("ls", "ls", "-l", (char *) 0);
  }

  if (ret > 0) {
    close(p[1]);
    dup2(p[0], 0);
    execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", (char *) 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @JuniorCompressor ,though i can't upvote it due to lack of scores.